# Azure Web app save temporary files limit

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage-files

I have need to store files temporary on my Azure web app (app service). I don't have to share these files between web app instances.

I have read (in the [kudu wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox)) that I can use the d:\local for such storage, but what limitations exists regarding the amount of data that can be stored there?

I have also read that it depends on the selected level (sku) of the web app (Basic, standard, premium) but I have not found any exact size limitations.

**Is there any way to determine this in runtime using code**?

**UPDATE:**
When I check the the Environment tab in Kudo on my Basic web app it lists

```
D:\home usage: 10,240 MB total; 10,072 MB free 
d:\local usage: 230,397 MB total; 198,341 MB free
```

But if I do a check using `System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives()` the D drive lists as

```
d:\ usage: 32,768 MB total;  12,083 MB free
```

*(Kudo shows a lot more than that for the d:\local drive.)*
Another peculiar thing is that you can navigate the filesystem in the Kudo console but the files I create on the web app can not be found there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [Kudu wiki page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-runtime-environment#file-system) has more info about it. Copying from there in the Temporary Files section:

> For Free and Shared sites, there is a 500MB limit for all these locations together (i.e. not per-folder). For Standard and Basic sites, the limit is very high (over 100GB).

Also, if you go to the Environment tab in Kudu, it tells you how much space is available (you care about `d:\local`), e.g.

`D:\home usage: 1,024 MB total; 616 MB free
d:\local usage: 500 MB total; 499 MB free`

Comment: I am confused by these numbers. On my Basic site, in the Environment tab in Kudo it lists

    D:\home usage: 10,240 MB total; 10,072 MB free 
    d:\local usage: 230,397 MB total; 198,341 MB free

But if I do a check using System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives() the D drive lists as a 32Gb drive with 11.8 Gb free (Kudo shows a lot more than that for the d:\local drive.
If I use the console in Kudo, none of the files created in the web app, can be seen.

Comment: Even so, do you have any idea on how to get these values by code? (see update above)

Comment: See the code [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/blob/be03dc69abc3624e92e73e17ae832d6b5e4c145e/Kudu.Services.Web/Env.cshtml#L38-L46) and [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/blob/be03dc69abc3624e92e73e17ae832d6b5e4c145e/Kudu.Core/Environment.cs#L308-L333)

Comment: For clarity to any others finding this page. The reason that you see different sizes for the folders d:\home vs d:\local vs d:\, is that the folders are UNC links to azure storage or local cache if you enabled it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-available-operating-system-functionality https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-local-cache

Answer (score 0):

You can find the disk space available to you for your Web Apps on their pricing page here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/.

Yes, the disk size varies by the app service plan you opt for. Currently it goes from 1GB of disk space (Free & Basic Plans) to 500 GB of disk space (for Premium Plan).