# Viewing file share associated to App Service

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-storage, azure-app-service-plans, azure-files

Where can I find the file share associated with the App Service?

I can view the files from Kudo console, but I don't see the share on my Storage Account using either the portal or Storage Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the files are backed by a storage account, it is in a platform account and not one of your own accounts. That's why you cannot see the files in storage explorer. It's also why you can create a Web App without specifying a storage account.

One exception is for Azure Functions on Consumption plan, where the user storage account is used, and you'd see the Azure Files in storage explorer.

Comment: Thank you David. Great explanation!! Follow-up question: On a previous answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/36893056/84395) you specified how `D:\home` and `D:\local` have different storage limits. I thought that the file share was mounted as D:\, so both \home and \local should have the same limits. Are \home and \local separate file shares?

Comment: Yes, only D:\home is storage backed. Local is on the local disk and not persistent